# How to serial write multiple data to Arduino using NodeJS serialport

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, serial-port, node-serialport

I am trying to write multiple data using the same port but I can not do it.
But `node-serialport` provides multiple data read function at the same time.
How I write multiple data at the same time

This way I tryout

```
- index.js-

const SerialPort = require('serialport'); 
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const port = new SerialPort('COM3', 9600);
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({delimiter: '\r\n'}));

function sendToSerial(datax, datay) {
  console.log("sending to serial: " + datax, datay);
  port.write(datax);
  port.write(datax);
}

parser.on('data', (data) => {
  
  const responseArray = JSON.parse(data);  // Incoming Data from arduino
  sendToSerial1(datax, datay);   // Send data to arduino
});
```

Arduino code

```
-arduino.ino-

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {

    if(Serial.available() > 0){
      int datax = Serial.parseInt();
      int datay = Serial.parseInt();
    }

    Serial.print(F("{\"temperature1\": "));
    Serial.print(t1);
    Serial.print(F(", \"moisture1\": "));
    Serial.print(h1);
    Serial.print(F(", \"temperature2\": "));
    Serial.print(t2);
    Serial.print(F(", \"moisture2\": "));
    Serial.print(h2);
    Serial.println(F("}"));
    
    delay(1000);
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure its the solution, but I'm guessing there is a bug in your code here....

```
  port.write(datax);
  port.write(datax);
```

Guessing the last argument is meant to be datay?